# Detecting if iOS is switched on

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Just a quick question, I'd like to know if it is possible in `Xcode` to detect if the `iOS` device is on and running?

If so, how?

I know I could use the `applicationDidEnterBackground` delegate to see if if it was closed, but the use could just be using another app. Thanks! :)

Comment: Uhm, how would one detect "off"? Your code cannot physically be running if the device is powered down.

Answer (score 2):

If `applicationDidEnterBackground`: is called your device is obviously ON.